# Read and parse a CSV file in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to read this CSV file:

```
http://www.bellewaer.de/salesdash/Gateway/GatewayExport.csv
```

There is problem with the CSV file. I can't parse it.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $csvFile = file('http://www.bellewaer.de/salesdash/Gateway/GatewayExport.csv');
    $data = [];
    foreach ($csvFile as $line) {
        $data[] = str_getcsv($line);
    }
    echo $data[0]['ExternalID']; //i have problem here
 ?>
```

Comment: this is how data looklike : http://prntscr.com/l1ea92

Comment: I really hope this is fake data in the CSV file - otherwise you may want to change that ASAP! Just saying...

Comment: Besides the fact the file hasn't got a valid csv format, you might take a look at the fgetcsv function also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
<?php
    $file = file('http://www.bellewaer.de/salesdash/Gateway/GatewayExport.csv');
    $data = array_map('str_getcsv', array_slice($file, 3));
    array_walk($data, function(&$a) use ($data) {
        $a = @array_combine($data[0], $a);
    });
    array_shift($data); # remove column header

    echo $data[0]['ExternalID'];
?>
```

(This code is shamelessly borrowed from the sample that [starrychloe](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#117692) wrote on the PHP doc page.)

Answer (score 0):

The CSV file is wrong. Delete first three lines (in notepad) and it will be ok :)

textbox1
(Web)Sales from: 20-Sep-2018 to: 27-Sep-2018

ExternalID,OrderID,OpenDate,....

Comment: OP still won't be able to access the data the way their code expects - `str_getcsv()` returns an array of column values, not an associative array of key-value pairs.  To use the first row in the CSV as keys to an associative array requires an extra step.